# Multiprocessing: How to determine whether a job is waiting or submitted?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

### Background

- A small server which waits for different types of jobs which are represented 
  as Python functions (`async_func` and `async_func2` in the sample code below).
- Each job gets submitted to a `Pool` with `apply_async` and takes a different amount of time, i.e. I cannot be sure that a job which was submitted first, also finishes first
- I can check whether the job was finished with `.get(timeout=0.1)`

### Question

How I can check whether the job is still waiting in the queue or is already running?

Is using a `Queue` the correct way or is there a more simple way?

### Code

```
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

def async_func(x):
    iterations = 0
    x = (x + 0.1) % 1
    while (x / 10.0) - random.random() < 0:
        iterations += 1
        time.sleep(0.01)
    return iterations

def async_func2(x):
    return(async_func(x + 0.5))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    results = dict()
    status = dict()
    finished_processes = 0
    worker_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    jobs = 10
    for i in range(jobs):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            results[i] = worker_pool.apply_async(async_func, (i,))
        else:
            results[i] = worker_pool.apply_async(async_func2, (i,))
        status[i] = 'submitted'
    while finished_processes < jobs:
        for i in range(jobs):
            if status[i] != 'finished':
                try:
                    print('{0}: iterations needed = {1}'.format(i, results[i].get(timeout=0.1)))
                    status[i] = 'finished'
                    finished_processes += 1

                except:
                    # how to distinguish between "running but no result yet" and "waiting to run"
                    status[i] = 'unknown'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just send the status dict, to the function, since dicts are mutable all you need to do is change a bit your functions:

```
def async_func2(status, x):
    status[x] = 'Started'
    return(async_func(x + 0.5))
```

Of course you can change the status to pending just before calling your `apply_async`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I was trying to avoid shared objects. The other suggestion to append the status before calling `apply_async` is a bit problematic in my opinion because `apply_async` gets executed immediately but only starts working when a place in the pool is available.